# SQL Server temporal tables - storing the user who deleted a row

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, temporal-tables

I am going to use temporal tables to keep a full audit trail of all changes to records in my key tables. One thing I have already implemented is each of those key record models implements:

```
public interface IAuditTrail
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The IdentityUser.Id (AppUser.AspNetUserId) of the user who updated (or created) this record.
    /// </summary>
    public string? UpdaterUserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IP address of the user who updated (or created) this record.
    /// </summary>
    public string? UpdaterIpAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And just before calling `SaveChangesAsync()` I first call (method added to my DbContext class):

```
public void SetAuditFields(IAuditTrail? primaryRecord, string? userId, string? userIpAddress)
{

    // if we have a primary, set it
    if (primaryRecord != null)
    {
        primaryRecord.UpdaterUserId = userId;
        primaryRecord.UpdaterIpAddress = userIpAddress;
    }

    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        if (entry.State != EntityState.Added && entry.State != EntityState.Modified)
            continue;
        if (entry.Entity is not IAuditTrail entity) 
            continue;
        entity.UpdaterUserId = userId;
        entity.UpdaterIpAddress = userIpAddress;
    }
}
```

This means for the INSERT and every UPDATE I have the logged in user who performed the action and the IP address they performed it from. This part is great.

But for a DELETE I don't have this. Is there a way with temporal tables to have a final row written that will have the UpdaterUserId and UpdaterIpAddress of the individual doing the delete? Is there some call I can make to add a row to the temporal table for this?

Comment: You need to do and update, save and then delete

Comment: @ErikEJ First off, great suggestion. I'll try and test of course, but is it safe to do an update and then delete in a single transaction. Will the update then **always** occur? Or is the database smart enough to ignore the update as the record is about to be deleted.

Comment: You need to call SaveChanges twice, but yes.

Comment: @DavidThielen, Are you working on the temporal tables?
You can use a trigger will run every time a deletion happens

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula A trigger won't help. I want to record who performed the delete and the trigger has no knowledge of the logged in user that clicked the button that caused my code to delete the record.